# Не удается прочитать csv модулем Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

у нас есть csv в кодировке utf-8, состоящий из данных спарсенных из вк.
В нем столбцы id группы, Название группы, Id пользователя.
Но по той причине, что в названии группы (второй столбец) могут быть какие угодно символы (скорее всего смайлы), pandas не может прочитать файл с ошибкой utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xbd
https://skr.sh/sESR8W6cEm6?a
Чтение файла - самое стандартное:

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\result.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', engine="python", encoding="utf-8", decimal=',')
 
print(df)
```

Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Значит файл не в кодировке utf-8

Comment: Разместите как код в вопросе первые пять строк csv файла.

Comment: Попробуйте таки разные кодировки, в том числе `cp1251`, и разные варианты `utf-16`